# Updating D3 V3 Zoomable Sunburst data breaks chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, web, data-visualization, sunburst-diagram

I'm new to programming D3, we are having a problem updating the sunburst chart without causing it to break its transitions. When the data is changed, parts of the chart stop resizing for the zooming feature and appear to be over each other. Additionally, I get errors resulting, apparently, from the interpolation of the flags each "arc" in the graph (i.e. Error:  attribute d: Expected arc flag ('0' or '1'), "…125862517296 0 0.987032831999999…".). We are using a tween that is specific for this problem and thus can't understand what might be causing it.
Since I'm inexperienced in this language I've spent several days on this problem only to see it come back. If any of you could help I would appreciate it immensely.

Here's a working fiddle that I created to illustrate our problem:
- https://jsfiddle.net/v9ab0vms/1/

The problem can be seen by waiting 5 seconds and clicking the "Commercial" and then "Communications" arcs. Causing the transition errors and breaking some of the arcs. Zooming the graph while the data gets changed causes it to break in other ways, any help on that would also be greatly appreciated. I was just trying to fix it step by step.

[Picture of broken chart arcs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3hnv.png)

The code has to be posted as well so I'm just inserting the two main functions for the sunburst:

```
function genSunburst2() {
  var width = d3.select("#container_sunburst").style("width").split("px")[0],
    height = d3.select("#container_sunburst").style("height").split("px")[0],
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

  var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

  var y = d3.scale.sqrt()
    .range([0, radius]);

  var color = d3.scale.category20c();

  var svg = d3.select("#sunburst")
    .attr("id", "sunburst")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .select("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

  var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .value(function(d) {
      return d.size;
    });

  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) {
      return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x)));
    })
    .endAngle(function(d) {
      return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x + d.dx)));
    })
    .innerRadius(function(d) {
      return Math.max(0, y(d.y));
    })
    .outerRadius(function(d) {
      return Math.max(0, y(d.y + d.dy));
    });

  function computeTextRotation(d) {
    var angle = x(d.x + d.dx / 2) - Math.PI / 2;
    return angle / Math.PI * 180;
  }

  function arcTween(d) {
    var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x, d.x + d.dx]),
      yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y, 1]),
      yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y ? 20 : 0, radius]);
    return function(d, i) {
      return i ? function(t) {
        return arc(d);
      } : function(t) {
        x.domain(xd(t));
        y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t));
        return arc(d);
      };
    };
  }

  function arcTweenUpdate(a) {
    console.log(path);
    var _self = this;
    var i = d3.interpolate({
      x: this.x0,
      dx: this.dx0
    }, a);
    return function(t) {
      var b = i(t);
      console.log(window);
      _self.x0 = b.x;
      _self.dx0 = b.dx;
      return arc(b);
    };
  }

  updateSunburst3 = function() {
    if (sunburstClick) {
      sunburstClick = false;
      return;
    }

    var root = createJsonDataset();
    // DATA JOIN - Join new data with old elements, if any.
    var gs = svg.selectAll("g").data(partition.nodes(root));

    // ENTER
    var g = gs.enter().append("g").on("click", click);

    // UPDATE
    var path = g.append("path");

    gs.select('path')
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .on("click", click)
      .each(function(d) {
        this.x0 = d.x;
        this.dx0 = d.dx;
      })
      .transition().duration(500)
      .attr("d", arc);

    var text = g.append("text");

    gs.select('text')
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return y(d.y);
      })
      .attr("dx", "6") // margin
      .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")";
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      })
      .style("fill", "white");


    function click(d) {
      sunburstClick = true;
      console.log(d);
      // fade out all text elements
      /*if (d.size !== undefined) {
        d.size += 100;
      };*/

      text.transition().attr("opacity", 0);
      console.log(path);

      for (var i = 0; i < path[0].length; ++i) {
        if (path[0][i] === undefined || path[0][i] === null) {
          path[0].splice(i, 1);
          --i;
        }
      }

      path.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attrTween("d", arcTween(d))
        .each("end", function(e, i) {
          // check if the animated element's data e lies within the visible angle span given in d
          if (e.x >= d.x && e.x < (d.x + d.dx)) {
            // get a selection of the associated text element
            var arcText = d3.select(this.parentNode).select("text");
            // fade in the text element and recalculate positions
            arcText.transition().duration(750)
              .attr("opacity", 1)
              .attr("transform", function() {
                return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(e) + ")"
              })
              .attr("x", function(d) {
                return y(d.y);
              });
          }
        });

      userSelection = undefined;
      purposeSelection = undefined;

      // TODO: alterar para ele ter em conta a hierarquia da selecao corrente
      // para so sair de uma hierarquia
      if (typeof d.name != "undefined" && d.name != "") {
        if (typeof d.size === "undefined") {
          userSelection = d.name;
          purposeSelection = undefined;
        } else {
          userSelection = d.parent.name;
          purposeSelection = d.name;
        }
      } else {
        // if only the user was selected, back out to no selection
        if (purposeSelection === undefined && userSelection != undefined) {
          userSelection = undefined;
          // if both the user and the purpose were selected, back out to just user selection
        } else if (purposeSelection != undefined && userSelection != undefined) {
          purposeSelection = undefined;
        }
      }

      applySelection();
    }

    // EXIT - Remove old elements as needed.
    gs.exit().transition().duration(500).style("fill-opacity", 1e-6).remove();
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Edit: To clarify:

- This is in D3 V3.
- We have two variables one with the full dataset
  and another with the "working" dataset. We apply filters to the full
  dataset and store the result in the working dataset.

Comment: You are using D3 v3 or v4?

Comment: And you want to be able to load different file into the graph and update the graph?

Comment: Hi! I added the clarifications to the OP. Thank you!

Comment: When I find time I will try it but can also try it by yourself: https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7030f35b72de721622b8 It updates the graph with data from new file. Also this one: http://bl.ocks.org/alansmithy/e984477a741bc56db5a5

Comment: Maybe bring the Sun into the initial state and then transition it into a new Sun with new data seemlesly. I couldn't draw the text of the arcs, so noobish of my side :D

Comment: I managed to update the sunburst correctly (as far as we can tell) but some of the arcs break. I tried reverting it to its initial state, but even then updating the data ended up breaking it.